# Foreign key mismatch - "password_resets" referencing "users" on dropColumn

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm trying to drop a column (lets call it fooboo) on 'users' table with migrations and i'm getting the next error:

> General error: 1 foreign key mismatch - "password_resets" referencing "users" (SQL: INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, password, fooboo, created_at, updated_at) SELECT id, name, email, password, fooboo, created_at, updated_at FROM __temp__users)

The `up()` function in migration class:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('fooboo');
        });
    }
```

This column in particular doesn't have any index, FK or anything that could create conflict. It is just a boolean with a default value `FALSE`.

I'm getting this error with sqlite when running my unit tests (phpunit). I can't solve this problem just removing the column on migration class that creates it, i need a new migration to run on production server.

Asking our friend google, i can only find this error associated with missed migrations, that's not my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line at very first:

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

and at the end add this line in last:

```
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

This will disable your foreign key constraint.

Comment: well, this works, but i don't think it's the way to solve this. As i said, my column is not a FK or anything that might have a conflict. I can also try to drop any other column from that table and i'm still getting the same error. I'll wait for another answer or explanation

Comment: can you share your table structure and foreign keys mapping ?

Comment: No, i can't, its not an open source project.